# Hazelcast nodes don't join the cluster

Tags: hazelcast

My hazlecast nodes established the socket already. But they don't join the cluster

```
2018-12-12 06:32:24.568  INFO 11 --- [thread-Acceptor] com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.TcpIpAcceptor      : [10.1.0.68]:5701 [dev] [3.10.4] Accepting socket connection from /10.1.0.67:44313
2018-12-12 06:32:24.568  INFO 11 --- [thread-Acceptor] c.h.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnectionManager       : [10.1.0.68]:5701 [dev] [3.10.4] Established socket connection between /10.1.0.68:5701 and /10.1.0.67:44313
```

I'm using the TCP-IP network join

[image]

[image]

My configuration as below:

```
<network>
    <port auto-increment="false" port-count="100">5701</port>
    <outbound-ports>
        <ports>0</ports>
    </outbound-ports>
    <join>
        <multicast enabled="false">
            <multicast-group>224.2.2.3</multicast-group>
            <multicast-port>54327</multicast-port>
        </multicast>
        <tcp-ip enabled="true">
            <member>task-controller-backup</member>
            <member>cdipp-task-controller</member>
        </tcp-ip>
        <aws enabled="false">
        </aws>
        <discovery-strategies>
        </discovery-strategies>
    </join>
    <interfaces enabled="false">
        <interface>10.10.1.*</interface>
    </interfaces>
    <ssl enabled="false"/>
    <socket-interceptor enabled="false"/>
    <symmetric-encryption enabled="false">
        <algorithm>PBEWithMD5AndDES</algorithm>
        <salt>thesalt</salt>
        <password>thepass</password>
        <iteration-count>19</iteration-count>
    </symmetric-encryption>
</network>
```

The logs are as below, I push the logs onto ELk stack, so the ording are ascending

```
December 12th 2018, 15:44:38.632[10.1.0.69]:5701 [dev] [3.10.4] [10.1.0.69]:5701 is STARTED
December 12th 2018, 15:44:38.609[10.1.0.69]:5701 [dev] [3.10.4] Hazelcast will connect to Hazelcast Management Center on address: 
http://hazelcast-mancenter:8085/hazelcast-mancenter
December 12th 2018, 15:44:38.559[10.1.0.69]:5701 [dev] [3.10.4] 
Members {size:1, ver:1} [
    Member [10.1.0.69]:5701 - 1294beca-b2d3-43ba-9435-1f4439615f40 this
]
December 12th 2018, 15:44:38.558[10.1.0.69]:5701 [dev] [3.10.4] Cluster version set to 3.10
December 12th 2018, 15:44:33.549[10.1.0.69]:5701 [dev] [3.10.4] Connecting to task-controller-backup/10.104.212.10:5701, timeout: 0, bind-any: false
December 12th 2018, 15:44:33.535[10.1.0.69]:5701 [dev] [3.10.4] Established socket connection between /10.1.0.69:42573 and cdipp-task-controller/10.98.68.83:5701
December 12th 2018, 15:44:33.533[10.1.0.68]:5701 [dev] [3.10.4] Established socket connection between /10.1.0.68:5701 and /10.1.0.69:42573
December 12th 2018, 15:44:33.531[10.1.0.68]:5701 [dev] [3.10.4] Accepting socket connection from /10.1.0.69:42573
December 12th 2018, 15:44:33.530[10.1.0.69]:5701 [dev] [3.10.4] Connecting to cdipp-task-controller/10.98.68.83:5701, timeout: 0, bind-any: false
December 12th 2018, 15:44:33.495[10.1.0.69]:5701 [dev] [3.10.4] [10.1.0.69]:5701 is STARTING
December 12th 2018, 15:44:33.493[10.1.0.69]:5701 [dev] [3.10.4] Plugin:active: period-millis:10000 max-deviation:33%
December 12th 2018, 15:44:33.482[10.1.0.69]:5701 [dev] [3.10.4] Plugin:active, period-millis:10000
December 12th 2018, 15:44:33.475[10.1.0.69]:5701 [dev] [3.10.4] Plugin:active: logPartitions:false
December 12th 2018, 15:44:33.472[10.1.0.69]:5701 [dev] [3.10.4] Plugin:active, period-millis:60000
December 12th 2018, 15:44:33.466[10.1.0.69]:5701 [dev] [3.10.4] Plugin:active, period-millis:60000
December 12th 2018, 15:44:33.464[10.1.0.69]:5701 [dev] [3.10.4] Plugin:active, period-millis:60000
December 12th 2018, 15:44:33.459[10.1.0.69]:5701 [dev] [3.10.4] Plugin:active
December 12th 2018, 15:44:33.457[10.1.0.69]:5701 [dev] [3.10.4] Plugin:active
December 12th 2018, 15:44:33.451[10.1.0.69]:5701 [dev] [3.10.4] Plugin:active
December 12th 2018, 15:44:33.450[10.1.0.69]:5701 [dev] [3.10.4] Diagnostics started
December 12th 2018, 15:44:33.438[10.1.0.69]:5701 [dev] [3.10.4] Starting 2 partition threads and 3 generic threads (1 dedicated for priority tasks)
December 12th 2018, 15:44:33.131[10.1.0.69]:5701 [dev] [3.10.4] Creating TcpIpJoiner
December 12th 2018, 15:44:32.031[10.1.0.69]:5701 [dev] [3.10.4] Running with 2 response threads
December 12th 2018, 15:44:31.960[10.1.0.69]:5701 [dev] [3.10.4] Backpressure is disabled
December 12th 2018, 15:44:31.499[10.1.0.69]:5701 [dev] [3.10.4] A non-empty group password is configured for the Hazelcast member. Starting with Hazelcast version 3.8.2, members with the same group name, but with different group passwords (that do not use authentication) form a cluster. The group password configuration will be removed completely in a future release.
December 12th 2018, 15:44:31.498[10.1.0.69]:5701 [dev] [3.10.4] Configured Hazelcast Serialization version: 1
December 12th 2018, 15:44:31.497[10.1.0.69]:5701 [dev] [3.10.4] Copyright (c) 2008-2018, Hazelcast, Inc. All Rights Reserved.
December 12th 2018, 15:44:31.496[10.1.0.69]:5701 [dev] [3.10.4] Hazelcast 3.10.4 (20180727 - 0f51fcf) starting at [10.1.0.69]:5701
December 12th 2018, 15:44:31.465[LOCAL] [dev] [3.10.4] Picked [10.1.0.69]:5701, using socket ServerSocket[addr=/0.0.0.0,localport=5701], bind any local is true
December 12th 2018, 15:44:31.453[LOCAL] [dev] [3.10.4] Could not find a matching address to start with! Picking one of non-loopback addresses.
December 12th 2018, 15:44:31.450[LOCAL] [dev] [3.10.4] Prefer IPv4 stack is true.
December 12th 2018, 15:44:31.449[LOCAL] [dev] [3.10.4] Interfaces is disabled, trying to pick one address from TCP-IP config addresses: [task-controller-backup/10.104.212.10, cdipp-task-controller/10.98.68.83]
December 12th 2018, 15:44:31.446[LOCAL] [dev] [3.10.4] Resolving domain name 'cdipp-task-controller' to address(es): [10.98.68.83]
December 12th 2018, 15:44:31.445[LOCAL] [dev] [3.10.4] You configured your member address as host name. Please be aware of that your dns can be spoofed. Make sure that your dns configurations are correct.
December 12th 2018, 15:44:31.443[LOCAL] [dev] [3.10.4] Resolving domain name 'task-controller-backup' to address(es): [10.104.212.10]
```

I found that the nodes are connected to others, but they cannot join the cluster

Comment: Could you share your configuration and subsequent log messages?

Answer (score 1):

It looks your host names are resolving to the addresses that are not in the interfaces of the running machine. See below log lines:

```
December 12th 2018, 15:44:31.449[LOCAL] [dev] [3.10.4] Interfaces is disabled, trying to pick one address from TCP-IP config addresses: [task-controller-backup/10.104.212.10, cdipp-task-controller/10.98.68.83]
December 12th 2018, 15:44:31.446[LOCAL] [dev] [3.10.4] Resolving domain name 'cdipp-task-controller' to address(es): [10.98.68.83]
December 12th 2018, 15:44:31.445[LOCAL] [dev] [3.10.4] You configured your member address as host name. Please be aware of that your dns can be spoofed. Make sure that your dns configurations are correct.
December 12th 2018, 15:44:31.443[LOCAL] [dev] [3.10.4] Resolving domain name 'task-controller-backup' to address(es): [10.104.212.10]
```

Later on, the instance complains about it could not find a matching address to start with, and picked one of non-loopback addresses. See below:

```
December 12th 2018, 15:44:31.465[LOCAL] [dev] [3.10.4] Picked [10.1.0.69]:5701, using socket ServerSocket[addr=/0.0.0.0,localport=5701], bind any local is true
December 12th 2018, 15:44:31.453[LOCAL] [dev] [3.10.4] Could not find a matching address to start with! Picking one of non-loopback addresses.
```

So, you need to check your DNS settings, and configure the hostnames you used to resolve an available TCP/IP address. After that, the members should join to the cluster.